# Solve $\cot x + 6\sin x - 2\cos x = 3$ for $0 < x < 360^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

What trigonometry identity should I use? I haven't learned about double angles, so I think it should not be used here.

I have reached this point $$1-\csc^2x + 6\cos x-2\cos^2x\cdot\csc x = 3\cot x$$

by the way, "csc" is "cosecant", right? I have just learned how to type in MathJax

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What have you tried?  For instance, have you tried expressing $\cot x$ in terms of sines and cosines?  Where does that lead you?

Comment: Please show your steps.  You may find it useful to use the align environment.  See this site's [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  I suggest converting everything into sines and cosines.

Comment: Hint…write $\cos x$ as $\cot x \sin x$ and factorise

Answer (score 4):

Starting with $$\cot x +6\sin x-2\cos x=3$$ write $\cos x$ as $\cot x\sin x$, assuming $\sin x\neq0$

Then you have $$\cot x +6\sin x-2\cot x\sin x-3=0$$
$$\implies(\cot x-3)(1-2\sin x)=0$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: This answer is to-the-point, and easily solvable.  Well done.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. Yes I can take it from here.  cos x = cot x . sin x was so smart! Where did you get the idea? Was it from the coefficient 6 and -2 and 3?

Comment: Yes that made me suspect it could be factorised

Comment: $\sin x\neq 0$ is implicitely assumed for the $\cot x$ in the original expression

Answer (score 1):

Let $c=\cos(x)$, then$$
\cot(x)+6*\sin(x)-2*\cos(x)=3\\
$$can be expressed$$
\frac{c}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}+6*\sqrt{1-c^2}-2*c=3
$$Multiplying through, we would be introducing roots where $\sqrt{1-c^2}=0\iff \left|c\right|=1$ which we'd have to take care to check, but are removing a singularity, so don't.$$
c+6*(1-c^2)-2*c*\sqrt{1-c^2}=3*\sqrt{1-c^2}\\
\iff c+6-6*c^2-(2*c+3)*\sqrt{1-c^2}=0\\
\iff c+6-6*c^2=(2*c+3)*\sqrt{1-c^2}\\
$$We can square both sides to remove the $\mathrm{sqrt}$,$$
\iff(6*c^2-c-6)^2=(2*c+3)^2*(1-c^2)\\
\iff36*c^4-12*c^3-71*c^2+12*c+36=-4*c^4-12*c^3-5*c^2+12*c+9\\
\iff40*c^4-66*c^2+27=0
$$This is a quadratic in $c^2$, the roots are $c^2=\frac{33\pm\sqrt{33^2-40*27}}{40}=\frac{33\pm3}{40}$, so $c^2\in\left\{\frac{3}{4},\frac{9}{10}\right\}$, so $c\in\left\{\frac{\pm\sqrt{3}}{2},\frac{\pm3}{\sqrt{10}}\right\}$. The first one is known to be $\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$ (due to the fact that it's equal to $-\cos\left(\frac{2*\pi}{3}\right)$, and $\cos\left(0\right)=1$ and $\cos\left(0\right)+\cos\left(\frac{2*\pi}{3}\right)+\cos\left(\frac{4*\pi}{3}\right)=0$ (due to moving along the edges of an equilateral triangle resulting in $0$ displacement) and $\cos\left(\frac{2*\pi}{3}\right)=\cos\left(\frac{4*\pi}{3}\right)$), however the second seems not to be a root of any Chebyshev polynomial (and its division by $\pi$ seems to return an irrational number), so while the solutions $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$ and $x=\frac{5*\pi}{6}$, the other two can only be expressed as $\mathrm{acos}\left(\frac{\pm3}{\sqrt{10}}\right)$. Equivalently, because we can compute $\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}$, it is $\mathrm{asin}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}\right)$, and $\frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}}{\frac{3}{\sqrt{10}}}=\frac{1}{3}$, so it is most simply $\mathrm{atan}\left(\frac{\pm1}{3}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

Similarly to the given aswer by David Quinn, we have

$$\cot x + 6\sin x - 2\cos x = 3 \iff \cot x + 2\sin x\left( 3- \cot x\right) = 3 \iff(2\sin x-1)\left( 3- \cot x\right) = 0 $$

As an alternative, by half-angle identities with $t=\tan \frac x 2$

$$\cot x + 6\sin x - 2\cos x = 3 \iff \frac{1-t^2}{2t}+6\frac{2t}{1+t^2}-2\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}=3$$

$$\iff t^4  -24 t^2 +2 t^3 + 10 t - 1=0 \iff (t^2 - 4 t + 1) (t^2 + 6 t - 1) = 0$$